# Android | Google PlacePicker API. OnActivityResult code not executed [Really weird behaviour]

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api, onactivityresult

I've a Fragment (support.v4) in a ViewPager with the which calls PlacePicker UI and then updated on a TextView. My code is as follows,

```
public void openPlacePicker() {
    try {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(getContext());
        // Start the Intent by requesting a result, identified by a request code.
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER);

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), getActivity(), 0);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Google Play Services is not available.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

And the OnActivityResult is,

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(TAG, "Request Code:" + requestCode);//This is printed
    if(requestCode == PLACE_PICKER){
        Log.d(TAG,"Reached in if()"); //Never printed
    }
    switch (requestCode) { //Never reached
        case PLACE_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, getContext());
                final CharSequence name = place.getName();
                //EventBus.getDefault().post(new NotifyEvent(NotifyEvent.NotifyType.PLACE_PICKED, (String) name));
            }
    }
}
```

So the problem is that, the conditional statements never gets executed. The Log before if() is printed. But the Log inside the if() is not printed.

Weird thing is the android-place-picker sample from GitHub is working fine.

I have tried the following:

- Clean Project
- Clear Data and re-install on device
- IDE clear cache and restart

Any ideas?

--EDIT--
Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.apps.maps">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.apps.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <permission android:name="com.apps.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <application android:name=".MyApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you enabled the Places API for Android in Google Developer Console

Comment: Of course I have. The PlacePicker will not show if it were not enabled.

Comment: May I show your Manifest.xml file also

Comment: What's the value of `requestCode`

Comment: 12. Defined in sfi PLACE_PICKER

Comment: Could you also add provide us with 1) the PLACE_PICKER declaration 2) the output of Log.i()?

Comment: switch code must be reached. You can also verify this by adding a `default:` statement inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread but it has helped me to resolve a similar issue to the original problem.  Raman Bhavsar's 10/10/15 comment was the right question to ask.  I had forgotten to enable the Places API in the Google Developer Console, and once I did I was able to hit my breakpoint in the onActivityResult method.